# Rails 6 webpacker. Js plugins not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-6

I am using Rails 6.
I am having problems with getting js plugins working.
I am trying to add toastr.js.

This what I have tried

```
yarn add toastr
```

This is how my application.js file look

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require('bootstrap')
require("jquery-ui")
require("packs/adminlte")
require("bootstrap-datepicker")
require("toastr/toastr")
```

This is how my environment.js file looks like

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker');

const webpack = require('webpack');

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery',
    Popper: ['popper.js', 'default']
}));

module.exports = environment;
```

If I use cdn or run the js code at `toastr/toastr`(node modules) in browser console everything works.

What am I missing?

Comment: Interestingly bootstrap-datepicker is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow below steps to use toastr JS in rails app with webpacker:

- Add toastr with yarn: `yarn add toastr`
- In your application.js:

  ```
  import toastr from 'toastr';

  toastr.options = {
      "closeButton": true
      .... add options here ...
   };

  global.toastr = toastr;
  ```

OR

```
toastr = require("toastr")
```

OR

```
import toastr from 'toastr/toastr';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `import toastr from 'toastr/toastr';` It worked for me.